# simple D3 linechart not loading data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I have been trying to create an extremely simple linechart in D3. The data is retrieved from a single array, nothing fancy, yet, no matter how hard I try, the data does not load to the chart. I have modified the code so many times and no solution seems to work. Please, bear in mind that I am a novice JS and D3 user.

```
<script>

var h = 400;
var w = 600;
var margin = 20;
var datac = [68, 1887, 1531, 645, 3870, 2759, 3064, 2188, 1451, 3336, 386, 883];



var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
.y(function(d) {return y(d);});

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w)
    .append("g");

svg.append("path")
.data(datac)
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", line);   

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d; })])
.range([0 + margin, h - margin]);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
        .range([0 + margin, w - margin]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
           .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - margin) + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin+ ",0)")
.call(yAxis);


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated your code like so:

```
var h = 400;
var w = 600;
var margin = 50;
var datac = [68, 1887, 1531, 645, 3870, 2759, 3064, 2188, 1451, 3336, 386, 883];

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin+","+margin+")")
        .append("g"); 

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(datac)])
    .range([0 + margin, h - margin]);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,datac.length])
        .range([0 + margin, w - margin]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
.y(function(d) {return y(d);});

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - margin) + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ",0)")
.call(yAxis);

svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", line(datac));
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Upg6/1/).